# Lvalue required as left operand of assignment while calling function

Tags: c

Trying to figure out what the issue is with my code, someone please help me out. The code is supposed to figure out and print the perfect numbers between 1 to 1000 and the number's factors. I'm trying to call the perfect(number) function but an error "Lvalue required as left operand of assignment " keeps popping up.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int perfect(int number);

int main(void){

    printf("The perfect numbers between 1 and 1000 are\n:");

    for (int number = 1; number <=1000; number++){
        perfect(number);
        if (perfect(number) = 1){
            printf("%d is a perfect number; ", number);
            printf("It's factors are = ");
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++){ //might need to change i<number
                    if (number % i == 0){
                        printf("%d", i);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int perfect(int number){

    int sum;

    for(int number = 1;number <= 1000; number++){
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= number/2; i++){
            if (number % i == 0){
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }

        if (sum == number){
           return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the consecutive lines `perfect(number);
        if (perfect(number) = 1){` are calling the function twice.  The first time is pointless since you ignore the return value from the function.  As an answer already notes, the second line needs `==` rather than `=` — a single `=` is assignment, and you can't assign directly to the value returned by a function (it isn't an `l-value`, which is something that can appear on the left-side of an assignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C (and a bunch of other languages that borrowed its syntax), `=` is the assignment operator, *not* the equality comparison operator.  Change `if (perfect(number) = 1)` to `if (perfect(number) == 1)`.